# SQL use of CASE to define where clauses

Tags: sql, sql-server, parameters, case

This is tsql.
I'm trying to contruct a query that let enduser define @ParamInput as either date or receiptnumber. Use case is that they want to view a specific receipt (date doesn't apply) or all receipts from specified date.

What i have thus far:

```
declare
@ParamInput as nvarchar(128) = '0000P01214000111942'

select
s.[Name] as Store
, se.[Date] as Date
, se.[Receipt No_] as Receiptno
, se.[Item No_]
, - se.[Quantity] as Quantity
, - se.[Net Amount] AS [Net Amount]
,- se.[Cost Amount] AS [Cost Amount]

from [company$Trans_ Sales Entry] se inner join [company$Transaction Header] th on th.[Store No_]=se.[Store No_] and th.[POS Terminal No_]=se.[POS Terminal No_] and th.[Transaction No_]=se.[Transaction No_] inner join [company$Store] s on s.No_=th.[Store No_]

where th.[Transaction Type]=2 and

case when @ParamInput like '%0P0%' then se.[Receipt No_] = @ParamInput
else (th.[Date] between @ParamInput and @ParamInput)
end
```

So as an example if ParamInput contains %0P0% then i'd like to use clause where se.[Receipt No_] = '0000P01214000111942' but if ParamInput doesn't contain this then i'd like to apply th.[Date] = @ParamInput (whatever value user has inputted).

How should the code for this look like?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: It's generally better to use AND/OR instead of case expressions in the WHERE clause.

Comment: Absolutely, i felt the original post contained enough info. So basically this is going to be used in PowerQuery where Parameter is defined by end user and i only want to use one single parameter so that they either give a specific date where they want to see the results from OR they give a specific receipt for which they want the data in select part to be presented to them. So Parameter could then either be a Date to be used for where clause on se.[Date] OR a receiptnumber which would then be used on se.[Receipt No_].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Dynamic SQL  .find the query below.

```
     declare
     @ParamInput as nvarchar(128) = '0000P01214000111942'
     declare @condition bigint=(select case when @ParamInput like '%0P0%' then 1
     else 0 end  as 'parametertype')
     DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX);
     SET @query =
     'select
     s.[Name] as Store
     , se.[Date] as Date
     , se.[Receipt No_] as Receiptno
     , se.[Item No_]
     , - se.[Quantity] as Quantity
     , - se.[Net Amount] AS [Net Amount]
     ,- se.[Cost Amount] AS [Cost Amount]

     from [company$Trans_ Sales Entry] se inner join [company$Transaction Header] th          
    on th.[Store No_]=se.[Store No_] and th.[POS Terminal No_]=se.[POS Terminal No_] 
   and th.[Transaction No_]=se.[Transaction No_] inner join [company$Store] s on 
   s.No_=th.[Store No_]

  where th.[Transaction Type]=2 and'
  if    (@condition=1)
  begin
   Set @query=@query + ' se.[Receipt No_] = ''' +@ParamInput+''''
  end
  else
  begin
  Set @query=@query + ' th.[Date] between ''' +@ParamInput +''' and '''+@ParamInput + 
 ''''

  end


 EXECUTE(@query)
```

Comment: I'm getting "Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 15
Incorrect syntax near 'P01214000111942'. " when trying this.

Comment: @FrankJonassen i have edited the query. Please check now.

Comment: @FrankJonassen no problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

Skip the `case` expression, use `and`/`or` instead:

```
where th.[Transaction Type]=2 and
      ((@ParamInput like '%0P0%' and se.[Receipt No_] = @ParamInput)
       or
       (th.[Date] between @ParamInput and @ParamInput))
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, getting error: "Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string." also as im reading this i'm not sure if the checks are correct. IF ParamInput contains '0P0 ' then it should input that value as where clause for se.[Receipt No_] if thats not the case then the value in ParamValue should be used for th.[Date] between ParamInput and ParamInput

Comment: you can't do this as you are testing your date against an invalid input format if the parameter contains a receipt no.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `case` to choose on which column you want to test so you need to test on both columns but then use `case` to check if it is a receipt number or not.
If it is not a receipt then set [Receipt No_] equal to itself, do the same for the date if it is a receipt.

```
WHERE th.[Transaction Type] = 2
AND
  se.[Receipt No_] = CASE WHEN @ParamInput like '%0P0%' THEN @ParamInput ELSE se.[Receipt No_] END
AND
  th.[Date] BETWEEN
              CASE WHEN @ParamInput like '%0P0%' THEN th.[Date] ELSE @ParamInput END
            AND
              CASE WHEN @ParamInput like '%0P0%' THEN th.[Date] ELSE @ParamInput END
```

As you have only 1 input parameter I don't think you need BETWEEN for the date check?

Comment: This worked okay, and you are correct on the dates between (was just testing a bit). Anyhow this ended up being very slow on execution time. @Its_Ady way of handling it worked lightning fast.